# Hide specific tag if found under (child of) another specific tag without ID or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide a specific tag (a 'path' tag) that falls under another specific tag (a 'text' tag) - problem is neither of these tags have been given an ID or class name (and I cannot give them one myself). The other problem is that there are many 'text' tags with other children that I cannot hide.

Here is the (simplified) code:

```
<text>
    <tspan> <!-- must not hide this child -->
</text>

<text>
    <path> <!-- Need to hide this child -->
</text>
```

The only attributes for these tags are style attributes.

I have been trying out different ways to hide this child but I cannot seem to find a way to specifically hide the 'path' child only without IDs or classes.

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: `$("text > path").hide()` ?

Comment: That unfortunately didn't seem to work. Would it be possible to select this specific tag and give it a style of "display:none"?

Answer (score -1):

If you are aware of which one exactly you want to hide, you can use .

Assuming your document is :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <text>
      <tspan> <!-- must not hide this child -->
    </text>
    <text>
      <path> <!-- Need to hide this child -->
    </text>
  </body>
</html>

var child = document.body.children[1];
child.style.display = "none";
```

Or you can simply iterate through the 'child' array and match the "path" elements to know when you need to hide it.

Comment: Would this not also hide the <tspan> tag? I need that child to be visible but I need the <path> child to be hidden.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. It is not flexible in any way. What if it is not the second child. What if there are more. What if the element is inside another tag?

Comment: Then simply do 'child.children[0].style.display = "none";'.

For a more generic solution with JQuery, do '$("text > path").hide();' as recommended by  Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy.

Comment: That is just to much work. Best is just to select the tag itself. Something like `document.querySelectorAll('text > path');`.

Comment: @putvande : He didn't asked for a JQuery solution, so I start giving a pure Javascript one. As you say, this is terribly not flexible and could be applied only for a very regular and well known pattern.

JQuery is better.

Comment: Than maybe that should be the answer.

Comment: That unfortunately didn't seem to work. Would it be possible to select this specific tag and give it a style of "display:none"?

Comment: Try the solution proposed by putvande.

Comment: None. I get no console errors. But the <path> I am trying to hide is still visible.